# How to set asp.net default theme in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, cookies, themes

I want to set my project with a default theme.

I have an existing project with multiples themes in it and running properly. 
In order to set default theme i did following things in the existing project-

**Content page (cs file)**

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Theme", "default");
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    base.OnInit(e);
    if (Request.Cookies["Theme"] == null)
    {
        Page.Theme = "default";
    }
    else
    {
        Page.Theme = Request.Cookies["Theme"].Value;
    }
}
```

Even I wrote the following thing in web.config file

```
<pages theme ="default" />
```

But even after trying all this the theme takes value as green as it was previously set in the existing project and i am not understanding where should i change more.

I checked the

- Master Page
- Content Page
- web.config

Is there any other file or any other way that the themes are set??

Comment: Is that because your new project is using your old project's cookie? Are they running on the same domain? Trying making the cookie name something different in the new project.

Comment: It can also be set in the global.asax.cs. Have you done a search of the project for ".Theme"?

Comment: @Cony hey yes i changed the cookie name from Theme to Theme1 and it got resolved..can u tell u hw can i achive it wid cookie name as Theme coz i need to use the same theme name

Comment: @MVC_Nhibernate also note, the preInit is going to run before PageLoad, so on first load, if you have an existing cookie of "green" then the theme will be green. You can also check to see if that cookie is getting set anywhere else.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev hey thanks for the info..yes u are right i did try checking where it is getting set but couldnt find it. can u suggest me some files where i should check.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+F lets you do a global search. Cookie can be set just about anywhere.

Comment: @MVC_Nhibernate: You can keep the theme name the same; the *cookie* name can be whatever you want, you just have to set and retrieve it with that name.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev hey i hav updated my question since PreInit ws getting called first so i placed the cookie code in Preinit but still it is taking the previous theme..please tell me how should i resolve this

Comment: @Cony i hav updated my question plz see if u can now find any solution from it